# How to use Pycryptodome AES to encrypt a string in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption, cryptography

I am new to cryptography and I have a question about some code.

```py
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Random import get_random_bytes

key = get_random_bytes(16)
cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_EAX)
ciphertext, tag = cipher.encrypt_and_digest(data)

file_out = open("encrypted.bin", "wb")
[ file_out.write(x) for x in (cipher.nonce, tag, ciphertext) ]
```

Is this code secure to implement directly? This code is taken from https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/examples.html#encrypt-data-with-aes
 **How do I encrypt a string using the key generated?**

Comment: EAX is considered secure when used correctly. You need to perform character encoding on your string to binary data / bytes before encrypting, usually UTF-8 is used for that. Then decode to string again after decrypting.

Comment: Is this code secure or do I have to modify if?

Comment: It looks OK to me, it is a single call to EAX and the nonce will be random generated. What else is there to tell?